# Lufthansa & Dolomiti, Europe to Asia

Tags: air-travel, airport-transfer, layovers, lufthansa

I am traveling from Prague to Hong Kong via Munich. It is my first time with transfers and I have no idea about the following.

**Transfer PRG (Dolomiti) -> MUN (Lufthansa) -> HK**

- Time for transfer (not boarding!) is just 45 minutes. I read some advice (small airport, same terminal, no care of baggage - one ticket), but do I have to pass through security again (I read about transits, but is it also the case  in Munich)?
- Is it possible to be on time? (I supposed yes, if company offers the ticket).
- What is your experience with Lufthansa (Economic Basic) and this (or similar) flight?

**Transfer HK (Lufthansa) -> MUN (Lufthansa) -> PRG**

- Time for transfer is about 6 hours. Could I leave (without baggage) the airport? This relates to the second question:
- Do I have to claim my baggage? Or does it "wait" 6 hours somewhere? If yes, can I reach it?
- Do I have to declare things like a bottle of alcohol, a mobile phone (200€) from HK? How much is it away from reality? It seems to me that everybody has something to declare... (I found the EU limit on alcohol is 1 liter. That couldn't be realistic).

Thank you very much for any answer on above topics although it is clearly simple for others. I have little experience and I have to be prepared.

Answer (score 1):

For your flight to Hong Hong, [it's possible to be on time](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/lufthansa-connecting-flight-at-munich-only-45-minutes-in-between-will-i-be-abl), though there's not much margin for delays. Munich is well-designed for tight connections. I've had that PRG-MUC flight park at a remote stand (a couple years ago, no idea if that's always the case), where you need to be bused to the terminal; that takes additional time. You will go through Schengen exit immigration in Munich, but you will not have to leave the secure area. If you're running late, seek help from Lufthansa staff to get to the front of any line. Since you've purchased a single ticket, Lufthansa will book you on a later flight at no charge if you're not able to make the connection.

For your return flight, you can leave the airport once you've gone through immigration. The airport has [regular train connections to the city center](https://www.munich-airport.com/public-transport-260822). Your baggage will likely be checked through during your layover, meaning you won't be able to reach it in Munich. Confirm this with the agent when you check-in in Hong Kong.

[Customs information for Germany](https://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/entering_germany_node.html) and [the Czech Republic](https://www.celnisprava.cz/en/clo/informace-pro-fyzicke-osoby/Pages/information-of-the-customs-administration-of-the-czech-republic-for-travellers-regarding-modifications-as-regards-imports-o.aspx) (the basic duty-free limits are the same) may be found online. Many travelers will indeed have nothing to declare, as they are not carrying more than these items. If you have something to declare, you'll find a ["goods to declare" red channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAP53.jpg) where you can speak to a customs officer and pay any applicable duty.

Have a great trip!

Comment: I am just wondering - duty free shops are also under regulation? I supposed that items bought here are excluded...

Comment: @user76316 Items purchased at a duty free shop in Hong Kong would count toward your limit, yes. They're not duty free when it comes to EU rules. Items already purchased within the EU are exempt (such as your clothes or electronics you take with you and bring back).

Comment: And one last question. What if I missed the flight. You are saying that Lufthansa will booked me in next schedule. But I see only one direct connection from Munich to HK per day. They have also indirect, but that means another layover, i.e. Zurich or Frankfurt. Which solution are they going to do?

Comment: @user76316 There's no guarantee. They'll generally try to rebook you on whatever will get you to your destination soonest if space is available, but it's also something you can discuss with the agent in Munich if necessary. If you have a preference, they may be willing to take that into account.