# Is schengen visa required for two layovers in Germany

Tags: transit-visas, layovers, short-connections, lufthansa, muc

I am flying from Charlotte, NC to Bangalore, India via Lufthansa and have two connecting flights. I fly from Charlotte to Munich, Munich to Frankfurt and Frankfurt to Bangalore. The layover time in Munich is 40 minutes. I arrive and depart Munich at Terminal 2.

Do I need a transit visa to go from Munich and Frankfurt? I have an Indian passport and a United States Visa? and if not, would 40 minutes be sufficient?

Comment: You need a Schengen visa to fly between Munich and Frankfurt.

Comment: To complete @phoog comment: You will have to go through passport control (entry in the Schengen area) in Munich. I never transited in Munich and I don't know how it is organised but with the additional delay of the border check, 40 minutes seems a bit short.

Comment: For question #1, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/lufthansa-connecting-flight-at-munich-only-45-minutes-in-between-will-i-be-abl.  For #2, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/is-a-schengen-visa-transit-visa-required-for-a-transit-flight-through-two-scheng

Comment: @NateEldredge, I have edited my question as I felt this is not a duplicate of the one you mention

Comment: The question about whether you need a transit visa is a duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/is-a-schengen-visa-transit-visa-required-for-a-transit-flight-through-two-scheng, then.  The system doesn't allow marking a question as a duplicate of two other questions, but the two questions I linked, between them, should answer everything you're asking.  If they don't, please explain what is special about your case.

Comment: 40 minutes is enough to change planes in MUC, even non-schengen to schengen. It is very common for european airlines to offer such short connections. However the MUC - FRA flight is an internal one, and you will need a Schengen visa.