# How much time do I require to make a connection in Munich airport?

Tags: transit, short-connections, muc, vueling

Next month, I need to make a connection in Munich Airport. My flight arrives to Munich at 17:35 (Lufthansa). After that, I want to take a flight that departs at 18:25 (Vueling Airlines) so **there is a window of 50 minutes between flights**.

**Is it sensible to book the second flight on the same day?** (I want to avoid having to wait 1 day in Munich to flight the next day)

I know it takes some time to make the connections and go trough security (I'm not checking-in any bags). On small airports it is totally doable, but I'm not sure if that's the case in Munich (May be the departure gate is close to the arrivals or miles apart?)

Both flights are international but within the European Union (Austria > Germany > Italy)

Comment: Are you wondering if you can make it if everything goes well, or are you wondering about your chances of making it if there are any problems (delays on inbound flight, long queue at immigration etc)?

Comment: Earlier questions about transit in Munich: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/is-1%C2%BD-hours-enough-for-a-transit-at-munich-airport?rq=1 http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/lufthansa-connecting-flight-at-munich-only-45-minutes-in-between-will-i-be-abl?lq=1 http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27466/travelling-from-dresden-to-delhi-via-munich-with-45-minutes-transit-time-is-it?lq=1

Comment: In your case, you won't have to go through passport control so the main question is whether you can book both flights as a single ticket.

Comment: The question is about whether it is reasonable to do it considering the time it takes to do all the movements :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Minimum Connection Time between flights landing in Terminal 2 (Lufthansa) and flights departing from Terminal 1 (Vueling) is 45 minutes.  Thus technically this is a valid connection.

However valid connection does not mean that you will make your flight - it just means that the airlines will let you book such a connection when booked on the same ticket.

If you are planning to book these two flights on the same ticket, then it's potentially worth the risk.  If you miss the outbound flight then it will be up to the airlines (most likely Lufthansa) to get you to your destination, either by moving you to a later Vueling flight, or more likely by putting you on one of their own flights to your destination.

However, if you are considering booking these flights on separate tickets then your chances of something going wrong are very high.  One of the reasons that MUC has such a low Minimum Connection Time is that they will make arrangements for getting people directly from inbound gate to outbound gate - especially in cases of delayed inbound flights (eg, using vehicles that drive across the airport itself). If you are on multiple tickets then they will not know that you are connecting, and thus will not make any such arrangements for you.

On separate tickets it is still possible that you will make your connecting flight, but personally I would never consider such a short connection. Your odds of missing the flight are too high, and if you do miss it you'll likely have to purchase a new ticket to get yourself to your destination.

Comment: Not sure if Vueling offers many connections, it's a low-cost carrier.

Comment: Is it possible to buy the second flight as part of the first, so they are on the same ticket? (I already have the first and it did'n buy it myself, a sponsor did it for me)

Comment: Nope. They would need to be purchased at the same time (and even then, a Lufthansa + Vueling ticket might not be possible)

Answer (score 1):

On the upside, your connection would be entirely intra-Schengen so you would not need to go through immigration or anything (note that not the body *EU* is relevant here but the member countries of the *Schengen agreement* — the latter includes e.g. Switzerland and Norway while it excludes, among others, the UK and Ireland). On the downside, Lufthansa and Vueling are in two different alliances and Terminal 2 is reserved for Lufthansa and Star Alliance flights only, meaning that you would need to change terminals.

Given that Munich is a rather large airport, the distances you may have to walk only to get from your arrival gate to the central area and then onwards into terminal one and to your departure gate can be surprisingly large. *If* you know your way around, *if* your luggage is through-checked, *if* your incoming flight is not delayed, *if* there are no long queues anywhere or *if* you are booking this on a single ticket, I would say you can make it — and the other answer also mentions Munich airport accomodating for transferring passengers by bringing them straight to their departure gate if need be.

You mentioned in a comment to on the other answer that you already have your first ticket into Munich, so your outbound flight out of Munich would *have* to be a second ticket — not to mention that they are not in the same alliance and Vueling is a low-cost carrier, all of which contribute to the low likeliness of the connection being part of one ticket. On two tickets, I would *not* risk it, even if I didn’t have to take care of luggage (e.g. hand luggage only).