# Munich Airport transit on two separate tickets

Tags: transit, germany, airports, munich, lufthansa

I will be arriving at Munich Airport Terminal 1 on an international flight at 7:45 PM, and my next flight to Berlin is at 9:45 PM from Terminal 2. I will be holding two separate tickets (Oman Air and Lufthansa). Is the transit time enough? I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Minimum connecting times are only guaranteed when you are ticketed through to your destination, which is not the case for the OP.

Comment: How much of a problem would it be for you if your inbound flight was a little late, and your missed your connection? Small delays are sadly fairly common, larger delays can and do happen, would either of those cause you massive issues?

Answer (score 3):

Munchen airport is relatively small and it has no common transfer zone between two terminals.

For you it means that you must pass the border during arrival.
It will takes a time (it depends of amount of passangers). Say at least 20 minutes on arriving. Don't forget about queues on departure - 10 minutes (it's always full of people).

Also since you fly by different airlines you should get your baggage after arriving to Munchen. Usually it takes 20-30 minutes.

Plus 10 minutes walk between terminals

So 10+20+10+20=1h

In a best scenario you will be in Terminal 2 at 8:45 PM

By rules of Munchen ariport you should check in with baggage not later than 40 minutes before departure.

So you have about 20 minutes on emergency case. I think it's enough.

Comment: Presumably the flight in on Oman Air is from Oman, so a journey time of something like 6 hours. A 20 minute delay on a journey of that length is moderately likely I'd say, in which case the OP is stuffed since it's two different tickets...

Comment: I will be flying into munich on business class so hopefully I'll be first at immigration and my bags would be out first. I will do the online check-in for my munich to berlin flight. Only to drop off my bags and clear security.

Comment: Do you think I could make it or am I being too smart :)

Comment: I think you can do it

Answer (score 1):

We already have questions about transfers in Munich, e.g. [Is 1½ hours enough for a transit at Munich Airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/is-1%C2%BD-hours-enough-for-a-transit-at-munich-airport?rq=1) Your situation is different because you have separate tickets but the answers seem encouraging. It's always risky especially if you have a long-haul flight in the mix and can't count on the airline's assistance. 2 hours is very short in any case but if there is a place where it can work, it seems to be Munich.

It might turn out to be costly but Munich is not far from Berlin and well connected to it so in the worse case finding another flight or even a train should not be an issue. I think you would have to wait for the next morning, though. If you can still do something about it, I would therefore try to get a better connection.

Also, do try to get your luggage checked through to your final destination. Oman Air [does list Lufthansa as an Interline partner](http://www.omanair.com/en/about-us/alliances-and-partners) and it might be possible even if you have separate reservations. If you manage to do that, you would save some time in Munich and avoid the whole waiting for luggage/luggage drop deadline issue so that you could still make it if your incoming flight suffers a moderate delay.

Comment: If I interline my bags from colombo to berlin could there be a issue because my muc to txl is a domestic flight. Shouldn't I clear customs in munich. Could this be done in berlin as well ? I will on biz class from colombo to munich.

Comment: @Ruchira Not necessarily, it's the way it works in the US but in Europe you typically clear customs at your final destination. The way the airports are organized, passengers go through separate arrival lounges and (where applicable) passport control depending on where they come from but end up in the same luggage collection area, before customs. Of course, different rules apply to domestic passengers but customs agents rely on tickets and other clues to determine which ones. You will need to clear immigration, enter the Schengen area and get your passport stamped (if applicable) in Munich.