# Would 1 hour layover be enough between Frankfurt and Munich if I have a transit visa and my final destination is US?

Tags: usa, schengen, transit, indian-citizens

I have an Indian passport and will be travelling to the US. I have two stops on Germany, first at Frankfurt and then at Munich. Lufthansa [suggests](http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/in/local?nodeid=3116855) that I need a transit visa which I will be getting. Both my tickets come under the same journey and are booked as one trip. I would be flying to Charlotte from Munich.

My layover time is just 55 minutes in Frankfurt. Will there be any immigration procedure for transit visa holders? Would it be possible for me to board my flight? Especially because [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/12830) claims that it is really difficult.

Comment: Is it all one ticket? And since you're changing planes twice, which airport is the one you've got the 55 minutes in?

Comment: I have updated the question details regarding this.

Comment: AFAIK you will entry the schengen area (for the flight between Frankfurt and Munich) and therefore a transit visa is not enough, you will need a schengen visa

Comment: Frankfurt has more than one terminal, so that'll make a difference - which terminals do both flights use?

Comment: Yes and I was checking the Lufthansa link which says "Schengen Transit Visa". Not sure if it is the same as a Schengen Visa

Comment: To be more specific, an “airport transit visa” is not enough, you will need a regular Schengen visa (which can be issued for transit purposes). You will need to go through the regular immigration lines, get a stamp, etc.

Comment: @Gagravarr My itinerary claims both are from the same terminal - Terminal 1. Flight LH-100 from Chennai (India) to Frankfurt and flight LH-428 from Frankfurt to Munich.

Comment: @Relaxed Yes that is the case. I have to apply for a Schengen visa but under the Transit category AFAIK

Comment: The most important thing is that you will need to go through a passport check and won't be able to board the internal Schengen flight from directly from the arrival lounge as you would for a non-Schengen flight. Depending on the airport/terminal, there might be a separate line/path for people who are only transfering. It does seem very short in any case.

Comment: Both my arrival at Frankfurt and Departure at Munich are from the same Terminal. Do I need to go through the passport check via immigration for this or is it just an extra scrutiny in my regular security check up? I don't have any baggage though. Since it is a single trip, baggage would be transferred directly I suppose.

Comment: @kesari It's a passport check, you will talk with a police officer who should look up your name in some databases and stamp your passport. They can ask more if they want but if everything looks fine, there is no reason they would. I don't know about Frankfurt but in Schiphol, they have separate booths for people going to and from the Schengen part of the airport airside but not to the luggage collection area. I have never waited very long but I hold an EU passport.

Comment: In all fairness, 55 minutes in pretty slim especially considering that you will pass thru immigration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all probability, you should be able to board the flight. I use the expression because this is not a matter of rules, but depends on various factors that cannot be predetermined, such as the punctuality of the flight that lands you into Frankfurt, the rush on the two flights, and the number of people doing the transition from this to that.

I had a similar experience once while flying Lufthansa from Bangalore to San Francisco. I had a little more time than you--90 minutes instead of 55, but guess what, my Bangalore-Frankfurt flight was late by around an hour. 30 minutes would have been impossible to make the connect but the airlines staff knew that, and they boarded all passengers of the incoming flight that had to connect to the next flight to San Francisco in a separate coach, took them to a special window where they got their passports stamped, and then back onto the coach and the plane for the connecting flight. I think the connecting flight was even delayed by a few minutes as 30 minutes would not have been sufficient to transfer 50+ passengers. It was smooth for passengers, though a little tiring of flying 20 straight hours.

One of my two check in bags didn't make it though. I got only one bag in SFO, and the other came to my hotel the next evening.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will have a customs check for entry into Germany at Frankfurt. But you may have a passport control check in Munich. When I travelled through Munich from the US to Israel and back, it was quick. I had mobility issues and I was able to make it slowly.

So I think you will be fine as Lufthansa planned everything via their booking. Call Lufthansa & look at the airport information below. If Lufthansa made a mistake in the transit times, it will be their responsibility to fix the problem.

Munich Airport Connecting info: https://www.munich-airport.com/connecting-flights-260553

Frankfurt Airport connecting info: https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights-and-transfer/transferring-at-fra.html

Comment: There should be no customs checks as customs checks are between baggage claim and the airport exit.  There will be two passport controls: in Frankfurt, to enter the Schengen area, and in Munich, to leave it.