# 1 and a half hour connection time in Munich with different airlines

Tags: transit, munich, muc

I'm currently booking flights and my one flight is packaged as
ARN -> MUC -> YYZ -> YOW

The connection time in MUC is 1.5hr. My flight flips from Lufthansa to Air Canada in MUC as well.

Is that enough time? How can i find out if my baggage is checked for me or if i need to grab it?

Comment: Did you book the complete flight at once? Then you can usually assume it wouldn't be offered if it did not work.

Comment: Yes I did @helm and im hoping thats the case

Comment: That's plenty. You will stay airside and your luggage will get automatically transferred to the Toronto flight (where you have to go through customs and recheck it).

Comment: @Hilmar in principle that's true, but I would advise the OP to double-check that information at the check-in/luggage delivery counter. These things can change and it's better to be safe. I have been in situations where I had to pick the luggage and check-in again. It shouldn't be the case, but the devil is on details.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of the timing, see [this other question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/). More generally speaking, quite often airports will list suggested connecting times. [Munich](http://www.munich-airport.de/en/general/faq/umsteigen/index.jsp) says 45 minutes minimum for transit if you're changing terminals, so doubling that should be fairly comfortable.

In terms of your luggage - I would expect them to check your luggage through, and for there to be no need for you to see it again until you get to Canada. For your own peace of mind, just doublecheck when you check it in. They should be able to tag it all the way to YOW.

You *will* need to pick it up at YYZ, and return it to be put on your connecting flight after clearing customs.

Answer (score 2):

Your flight would be entirely on Star Alliance carriers and thus in Munich’s terminal 2. You would be incoming on a Schengen flight and transferring to a non-Schengen flight. Furthermore, all flights are on the same ticket.

Terminal 2 is just one long building plus a smaller satellite building; the two are connected by an automated people mover underground. The main building is almost 1 km long which means an average walker should be able to get from one end to the other in around 15 minutes – plus, there are conveyor belts to speed up the process. The satellite is only around 600 m long.

The Schengen and non-Schengen parts of the airport are realised as different storeys within the same building. If you were coming from landside, the Schengen storey is the direct continuation of check-in/security while the non-Schengen storey is up one floor. There is one central immigration control at the centre of the main terminal building almost exactly where the APM from the satellite terminal arrives. Wherever your flight from Stockholm arrived, you will need to make your way to this central location, go upstairs, pass through exit immigration and then navigate your way to your departure gate on the upper storey (potentially taking the APM back to the satellite).

Munich airport advertises a minimum connection time of 45 minutes which is ample time to get from A to B within terminal 2 and the satellite.

As for your luggage, I have not yet come across any single-ticket connection that would require picking up and rechecking bags in Munich. The main reason this is done in places like the US, Canada or Japan is for customs: in these countries, customs inspections are performed at your first port of entry. In the EU, however, customs inspections are performed at your final destination. On your flight from Stockholm to Canada, your final destination is not in the EU so Munich airport wouldn’t care. On a potential return flight, your final destination is not in Germany so although customs are harmonised across the EU it is the Swedish authorities’ duty to examine, not the German ones’. Your luggage will most likely be checked through all the way from Stockholm to Toronto (where you will pick it up, pass Canadian customs and recheck it) on your outbound flight and if there is a return it will be checked all the way through to Stockholm on your return.

Of course, you can confirm this on check-in/luggage dropoff either by asking the person at the counter or by checking the luggage tag.