# Are 45 minutes enough for a layover in Munich Airport (from T2 to T1)?

Tags: short-connections, muc

Travelling from Lyon to Bucharest via Munich, had my eyes on a ticket from Lufthansa. The trouble is that I would arrive at 21:30 and have only 45 minutes to get from Terminal 2 to Terminal 1, is it doable? Does anybody know if the airport/airline can arrange some kind of pick up at the gate? I've been to Munich, the airport was not very crowded, if I remember correctly.

Comment: You might want to see [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/is-1%C2%BD-hours-enough-for-a-transit-at-munich-airport?rq=1) also for some other tips...

Comment: Just had to switch terminals in Munich last month but not the same as yours. Considering it takes about 20 mins or to get off the plane, without accounting for possible delays, I would say this makes it very likely you would miss your connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

45 minutes is fairly tight, but probably doable if you're by yourself and coming from an EU country.  I had a 1.5 hour stopover coming from the US and made it in sufficient time that 45 minutes would have been manageable, barely, with my wife and two children.  You don't have to check/recheck bags or anything like that I don't believe (at least from the US you don't - I don't know if a Schengen area country would change that).  Passport lines weren't long at all when we traveled through, on a relatively busy weekend day mid-day.

One thing to note: if your second flight is Germanwings (Lufthansa's budget airline), or even some Lufthansa operated smaller flights, it may be a bus ride to the airplane; many departures in Munich are accessed via bus (and some inbound, I believe, though not mine from the US).  That could add a bit of time.

Comment: As the note on Kate's answer on the linked question above said - this is very different if you have multiple bookings.  One booking this would feel possible, as the airline would make up for delays.